# Method must have return type error c#

Tags: c#, return-type

I keep getting this error

> Method must have a return type

For my code below. Can you help me figure out why I am getting this error?

```
namespace Group23
{
    class PacMan : Bots
    {
        Image rightFacingImage = Image.FromFile("Images\\pac32_right.png");

        public PacMan(int newXPos, int newYPos)
            : base(newXPos, newYPos)
        {
            this.TheImage = rightFacingImage;
        }

        //draw pacman method
        public PaintBot(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage(TheImage, new RectangleF(this.CurrentXPos, this.CurrentYPos, 20, 20));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public **void** PaintBot...

Comment: When changing to public void PaintBot, there is error messages "cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'internal' inherited member", from another class.

Comment: @ColinO'Croidheagain Please study basic c# syntax and language rules. there are plenty tutorials available.

Comment: @ColinO'Croidheagain: Don't know why you ommited return type of the functions. Thats a must. And do declare your class with a access specifier.  For example 'public class PacMan'. And lastly as Alex said, have you started to learn c# very recently?

Comment: Colin is saying that he gets an error when adding `void`, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Colin, does the base class `Bots` have a `PaintBot` method, and how is that method declared?

Answer (score 1):

A method must always have a return type; in your case, it seems you do not want to return anything, just perform an operation.  So insert "void" as such in the definition:

```
public void PaintBot(Graphics g)
```